# Inconsistent tableView contentInset Behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I am experiencing issues with setting contentInset on a tableView behaving inconsistently, depending on when it is called. I am using the following:

```
let edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 52, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
tableView.contentInset = edgeInsets
tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = edgeInsets
```

The top value is hard set to 52 there for testing, but in practice will be calculated from another view.
I am doing this because I need to have a view pinned to the top of a table view controller.
The behaviour I am experiencing is that if I use that code in the viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear functions, it works as I would expect. The tableView is below the pinned view and scrolled to its top (so all its content is visible). However, at that point, the pinned view has not been laid out, and its height is 0, so I can't use it to correctly set the top of the content inset (hence the hard 52).

If I use the above code from the viewDidLayoutSubviews function, which is where I have had it the whole time, it does not have the same results. The insets are actually set, but the tableView is also scrolled that much down, hiding its top rows behind the pinned view. I can then scroll up to see the top cells, and the tableView is then inset under the header, but it shouldn't start scrolled like that, and I have no idea why it is.

Comment: Is there a reason you want the cells to "scroll up and under" a view, instead of constraining the top of the tableView to the bottom of your "another view"?

Comment: @DonMag I tried this initially, but my understanding now is that, for a UITableViewController, the top level view is the tableView. So as far as I am aware, I can't add the header view to anything else, and I don't think I can have the tableView's top constraint be the header's bottom, as the heard is actually inside the tableView. Unfortunately I have to use a UITableViewController, or this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: *"... I have to use a UITableViewController"* Do you really? Assuming there is a valid reason, you may be better off using your "another view" as the **Section Header View**. Adding subviews to a tableView is *generally* problematic.